# populating fullcalendar with json data through sinatra url

Tags: json, sinatra, fullcalendar

We am trying to get a json feed to populate a FullCalendar application. We are using sintara and by implementing the sinatra-contrib gem we are creating a url which contains the relevant json data.

Below is the code we are using for FullCalendar in our index.erb file.

`$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      events: '/example.json'
});`

and this is the code in the sinatra server file we are using to test with, as eventually we want to populate by using data in a postgres database.

`get '/example.json' do
  json :title => 'paul', :id => "1", :start => "2015-03-11T15:25:00", :end => '2015-03-11T15:55:00'
end`

When we run this we get the following message in the terminal, which would suggest the call was successfully made, but the calendar does not get populated with the test event.

`[11/Mar/2015:18:46:41 +0000] "GET /example.json?start=2015-03-08&end=2015-03-15&_=1426099601014`

We are able to populate the calendar manually by adding the start, end, and title details to the events FullCalendar section.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like that :

```
require 'json'

get '/example.json', :provides => :json do
    {:title => 'paul', :id => "1", :start => "2015-03-11T15:25:00", :end => '2015-03-11T15:55:00'}.to_json()
end
```